# QStandarditem reject QString in constructor

Tags: c++, qt, constructor

I'm programming with c++ in Qt. When i construct `QStandardItem` it don't accept the `QString` declared before:

```
    file_content = new QString(textstream->readAll().mid(10,2)) ;
    standard_model->setItem(0,0,new QStandardItem(file_content));
```

But when I tried `QStandardItem("example")` it works.

Comment: What does "reject" mean? Do you get an error message or something?

Comment: What is standard_model?

Comment: @user3561614 presumably it is a `QStandardItemModel`

Comment: I mean when i compile it it shows "invalid conversion from 'QString' to 'int'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is that you are using a dynamically allocated string. The constructor for `QStandardItem` expects a `QString &`, not a `QString *`.

Since the pointer is basically an integer, using a pointer confuses the compiler to resolve to the `QStandardItem(int rows, int columns = 1)` constructor.

It will work if you `standard_model->setItem(0,0,new QStandardItem(*file_content));` but the appropriate thing would be to:

```
QString file_content = textstream->readAll().mid(10,2);
standard_model->setItem(0,0,new QStandardItem(file_content));
```

`QString` uses dynamic allocation internally and it is implicitly shared. There is ABSOLUTELY no reason to use dynamic allocation for it.

Don't use dynamic allocation unless you know you have to. In Qt, the rule of thumb (with very few exceptions) is if it is a `QObject` derived, you should allocate dynamically, as such objects have unique identity and cannot be copied, whereas Qt's container classes use CoW and are implicitly shared - they are very efficient to pass even by value and in most of the cases the proper thing would be to put them on the stack rather than on the heap.

Comment: @Artifex12 - see the addition I made to the answer, it will save you trouble working with Qt.